# Why did Fermina Daza reject Florentino Ariza?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, love-in-time-of-cholera

In *Love in the Time of Cholera*, first time Florentino Ariza saw Fermina Daza after she came back from the mountains, she rejected him. Why did she Reject him? given that in the ending of the story we see that she kept his hair, photos and letters.. means she never stopped loving him, so why did she reject him even before meeting the Doctor ?